# How can I label the axes of a grid of subfigures?

Tags: floats, subfloats

Is it possible to make a 3 by three grid of plots in a latex figure and then label only the columns and rows, rather than needing captions for each? So for example, I'd like columns to be labelled A, B and C and the rows 1, 2, and 3. I'd then be able to reference square (2, B) as the middle square.

I'm using a figure environment with 9 subfigure environments

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img2}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img4}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img5}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img6}
\end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img7}
    \caption{Smad7 reproduced}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img8}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/path/to/img9}
\end{subfigure}


    \caption{}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: it sounds like you can just remove all the subfigure markup and have a tabular with an `\includegraphics` in each of the top  left 9 cells and a text in the last column and row, then a single `\caption` for the whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tikz package to make one or more `foreach` loops and the calculations you need.

**foreach command**

`\foreach` is a command that starts a loop. It's syntax is `\foreach \x in {list} {commands}` where \x can be any variable name we want (like \row or \col) and list can be a full list separated by comma (like `{1, item 2, third item, 4}`) or if it just numbers, can used with dots to complete (like {1,2,...,9} or {3,6,...,15}). `commands` can be many commands that you want to repeat (it is like a for loop of python). **Note: foreach loop runs inside a environment and there are some limitations on commands you can use but this is somehow advanced info for now**

**pgfmathsetmacro command**

`\pgfmathsetmacro` is a command included in the packages loaded by `tikz` that is used to give a numerical value (float or integer) to a variable. If you want an integer result you have to put the operations inside `int()` function.
I used this command to calculate the variables `\totalCount` (that is a counter for the figures -from 1 to 9 here-) and to find out if I am going to start a new row after the current image (`\newRow` variable is 0.0 for these values of \totelCount that can be exactly divided by 3 - see python modulo ...I think there is a modulo for pgfmathsetmacro too but didnt used it- ).

**Additional info:**

To check something in python you use conditional statements like `if`... The same is used in LaTeX but for integer numbers it is `\ifnum...\else...\fi` and for floating point numbers we can use `\ifdim...\else...\fi`. (`dim` comes from dimensions because for LaTeX floating point numbers are most of the times used as lengths (So there is added a pt in my `\ifdim` command below))

The last part is `\xdef` command that defines a variable after extending its result and makes it global too (It is a big story about that... Please search for "latex def,edef,gdef and xdef" etc)

**The code is like this:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%opening
\title{}
\author{Kostis Leledakis}
\newcounter{myfigcol}
\newcounter{myfigrow}
\def\myspace{\hspace{5pt}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\foreach \row in {1,2,3} {%
\foreach \col in {1,2,3} {%
\setcounter{myfigcol}{\col}%
\setcounter{myfigrow}{\row}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\totalCount{int(\col+(\row-1)*3)}%
\xdef\totalC{\totalCount}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\newRow{\col/3-int(\col/3)}%
\xdef\rowC{\alph{myfigcol}}%
\xdef\colC{\arabic{myfigrow}}%
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\rowC-\colC}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-\rowC}%
        \caption{\centering Smad\totalC{} reproduced or image: (\rowC-\colC) etc}\label{fig:First\totalC}%
\end{subfigure}\ifdim\newRow pt = 0pt\space\else\myspace\fi%  
}
}

    \caption{My First figure}\label{fig:First}
\end{figure*}

In the figure \ref{fig:First3} included inside \nameref{fig:First}   as :\nameref{fig:First3} or else in \Cref{fig:First3}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I used: `example-image-\rowC` for my images but you can use

```
/path/to/image\totalC
```

**For additional or more specific info do not hesitate to ask.**

Comment: the counter have been corrected to use rows first and then columns. So, the (a-3) caption starts like: Smad7 etc...

Comment: Hi koleygr, thanks for the answer. It looks like it is precisely what I'm after. However, I'm fairly new to Latex so could I ask you to put a few more comments in the your answer to brake down the logic of what your doing. I'm from a python background so familiar with flow control structures but you've use a lot of commands which are unfamiliar to me. Thanks again,

Comment: Ok @CiaranWelsh... Just commenting the code and improving the answer...

Comment: @CiaranWelsh I added some info but did not had the time to comment the code too... I will take a look to your possible questions tomorrow.