# How to annotate a figure with latex?

Tags: floats, subfloats, labels

I would like to annotate a figure with subfigures using latex such that the columns are labelled 'models' 1 -3 and rows labelled 'parameter 1 - 5'. Here is an example of desired output:

[image]

The only difference is that I would like the row annotation to be horizontal? Is this possible ?

Please note, I'm reasonably new to latex so I'm okay with the simplest solution and not necessarily the most elegant. Thanks

## Edit

Just to address a question in the comments, this figure is being generated using figure and subfigure environments.

Comment: Does the 3x5 panel image already exist, and so you are talking about adding text over an existing image, or are you hoping to incorporate these annotations into the composite, *as it is being constructed from sub-panels*?  If the former, then an approach might work like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex

Comment: No I'm constructing the figure using figure and subfigures. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You really need to provide a minimum working example of code that constructs your image array, to give those who would help you a place to start.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think the OP uses something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396691/120578... But I agree that he have to give us the specific part of his code  as a MWE. Just giving the above link to help possible users that want to answer not to start from zero point.

Comment: Apologies for not providing the code. Turns out that the information in the link worked for what I want. I'm happy to accept an answer, delete the question or mark as duplicate (though it probably isn't exactly a duplicate). Thanks for the info!